# React Router HashRouter not redirecting unknown routes to PageNotFound

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using React Router(v6) with a HashRouter for routing in my application. I've set up my routes as shown below:

```
<HashRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="about-us" element={<AboutUs />} />
    {/* ...other routes */}
    <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
  </Routes>
</HashRouter>
```

The goal is to redirect all unknown routes to the PageNotFound component. However, I'm encountering an issue where anything after / without a hash (#) is being redirected to the home page instead of the PageNotFound component.

Please help me to achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: If the entry point into your app is `".../#/"` then anything prior to this, e.g. `".../"`, means the app isn't loaded yet and so the router can't do anything. If the app hasn't been accessed yet there is nothing it can do. You could perhaps configure this server-side to redirect `".../"` into your app so the app is mounted and can then handle any internal routing/navigation actions.

Answer (score -1):

If all you're looking for is to redirect all unknown routes I would suggest BrowserRouter instead as it's been implemented since earlier versions of react-router-dom.

Ex. route `/hello` does not exist so we're redirected to PageNotFound.

```
*index.js* 
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'; 

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)

*App.jsx*
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"; 
{/* import all other components/pages here */}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      {/* main routes */}
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />

      {/* catch unknown routes */}
      <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}
```